# How do I enable mbstring extension on PHP 5, Fedora server

Tags: php, apache, fedora, mbstring

I need to add the mbstring extension to an install of PHP 5.2.6 on Apache/2.2.11 (Fedora). We have dynamic extensions enabled so I really think all I need is the .so file and .ini files, correct? Can I simply drop these files in and make it work or do I have to recompile PHP? If it's simply upload and go, where can I get the files I need?

Comment: See this [how-to-install-php-mbstring-extension-in-ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491629/how-to-install-php-mbstring-extension-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try `yum install php-mbstring`. You may then need to restart apache, e.g. `/sbin/service httpd restart`.

You can also use `yum info "php-*"` to find a list of other php packages available.

Comment: I get `There are no activated repos`

Comment: @EdwardBlack For more modern Fedoras they've replaced yum with dnf. I don't have an install to hand to check, but you could try the same commands with dnf not yum? Alternatively you don't have any activated yum repos for some reason - is it a normal Fedora install? Look in /etc/yum.repos.d.

Comment: sorry, I missed the info that this is about fedora. I have normal linux.

Comment: Oh OK - it'll still be a specific distribution, though? If it's Debian / Ubuntu then you want to use apt or apt-get, but I forget the exact syntax sorry (and am on rubbish internet here)