# using mysqli on fedora linux

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fedora

I am trying to use mysqli on my fresh Fedora 17 installation. I installed php, mysql-server and php-mysql. Still, the following code reports an error:

```
 <?php

 if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {

     echo 'We don\'t have mysqli!!!'; 

 } else {

     echo 'Phew we have it!'; 

 }

 ?>
```

php_info tells -with-mysqli=shared

What should I do then?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796841/how-do-i-enable-mbstring-extension-on-php-5-fedora-server but instead you have to use php-mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have to enable it in the php.ini under [extensions] section

Answer (score 0):

Your code will be more efficient like that:

```
if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') || !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
    echo 'We don\'t have mysqli!!!'; 
} else {
    echo 'Phew we have it!'; 
}
```

In this case will check if the PHP have the mysqli and if the MySQL extension is loaded in the php.ini, if not open php.ini and add the mysqli extension.
To view the php.ini use

```
php -i
```

in the command line.
mysqli is supported after MySQL 4.1+